# [zguide]pyzmq publish don't work

Tags: python-2.7, zeromq, pyzmq

I download the zguide source from github.
I find the python example code-wuserver.py doesn't work.
Run wuserver.py and wuclient.py,wuclient.py can not recv any data,But if I run the c code-wuserver.c,wuclient.py can recv data.

wuserver.py

```
#
#   Weather update server
#   Binds PUB socket to tcp://*:5556
#   Publishes random weather updates
#

import zmq
from random import randrange


context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

while True:
    zipcode = randrange(1, 100000)
    temperature = randrange(-80, 135)
    relhumidity = randrange(10, 60)

    socket.send_string("%i %i %i" % (zipcode, temperature, relhumidity))
```

wuclient.py

```
#
#   Weather update client
#   Connects SUB socket to tcp://localhost:5556
#   Collects weather updates and finds avg temp in zipcode
#

import sys
import zmq


#  Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print("Collecting updates from weather server...")
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

# Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
zip_filter = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "10001"

# Python 2 - ascii bytes to unicode str
if isinstance(zip_filter, bytes):
    zip_filter = zip_filter.decode('ascii')
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, zip_filter)

# Process 5 updates
total_temp = 0
for update_nbr in range(5):
    string = socket.recv_string()
    zipcode, temperature, relhumidity = string.split()
    total_temp += int(temperature)

print("Average temperature for zipcode '%s' was %dF" % (
      zip_filter, total_temp / update_nbr)
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info (zeromq, pyzmq versions, OS, etc.)? How exactly are you running the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried it and there's no anything wrong. You could modify the `wuclient.py` code to see what has been transfered:

```
for update_nbr in range(5):
    string = socket.recv_string()
    zipcode, temperature, relhumidity = string.split()
    print(string)    # add this statement
    total_temp += int(temperature)
```

Then, you should run `wuclient.py` **first** and then `wuserver.py`.

P.S.: The zguide documentation provides a very clear method to debug the missing message problem which could be very helpful. Here's [Missing Message Problem Solver](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver)